# Facebook Unity Plugin v6.0 - crash on Kindle Fire if you login, cancel login, then login again

Tags: facebook-unity-sdk

(This isn't a question, it's a bug report.)

Facebook Unity Plugin v6.0 - crash on Kindle Fire if you login, cancel login, then login again.

I'm on Unity 4.5.3 (latest).

You can reproduce this in the Facebook test scene.

1. Install to your Kindle Fire
2. I don't have the Facebook app installed, so it's using the web flows (not the native FB app)
3. Press FB.Init
4. Press Login
5. Cancel the login via the "X" button
6. Press Login again
7. Crash

Any workarounds?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok have a work around.  BTW this is also a problem on Galaxy 3, my guess is most devices if not all devices.

Fix.  In the login call back if you did not login correctly ie is_logged_in false then call FB.Init(somemethod) again.  Yes you will get a warning about it not suppose to be called twice but it works.  Just make sure if you are logging into facebook in the called back of you init create a new empty one otherwise round and round you go.

Steps to repro are the same basically as yours however you can also get it with the back button and canceling permissions.

1. Login.
2. Back button when it takes you to facebook OR cancel on permissions.
3. Take you back to app.
4. Login again.
5. Crash.

Also appears to only happen on the facebook app itself NOT if you dont have FB installed and using the browser.

Comment: I found a duplicated thread with same issue, and according to the comments there this workaround can lead to crash, quote:
"This one solved one issue. But, if you success login and logout, Then you login again, it will crash. It only work for login, cancel and login loop."
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25751057/facebook-unity-sdk-6-0-crash-app-at-second-login/25751554#25751554

Comment: So it should be fixed by Facebook devs as fast as possible.